# Dynamic sorting of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working of datagrid sorting. But GridViewStudents.dataSource is returning null in sorting function. I tried using session & viewstate. But doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

My asp code for datagrid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewStudents" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                            onsorting="GridViewStudents_Sorting" ></asp:GridView>
```

Sorting function:

```
protected void GridViewStudents_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dataTable = GridViewStudents.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        GridViewStudents.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

        GridViewStudents.DataSource = dataView;
        GridViewStudents.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Sorting helper function:

```
private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;

        case SortDirection.Descending:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}
```

Comment: Do you rebind your GridView on PageLoad?

Comment: I'm binding this way

if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadData();
}

Comment: Your Gridview has to be rebound on each roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

Apply automatic sorting mode

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColName"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

Try this....

DataGridView control is sorted using a column with a SortMode property value of `Automatic`, a sorting glyph is automatically displayed in the column header.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you rebind your Gridview on each roundtrip. The datasource of a gridview is not automatically stored in gridview or viewstate. If you need to access the datasource, you need to propagate the datasource first.

Comment: Actually a webservice is returing a dataset. So, I am trying to work on dataset which is returned in first roundtrip.

Comment: Then you need to cache the data or you try the automatic sort option offered by @mahi.

Comment: Hello Schadensbegrenzer. I made dataset object static. 
Thank you for attension.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
Hope it is useful for others.

For anyone who come across DataGridView sorting problem.
Remember 4 steps.

1. Declare global dataset object

   ```
   static DataSet ds = null;
   ```
2. Load data to grid

   ```
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       loadData();  
   }
   ```
3. Write sorting function

   ```
   protected void GridViewStudents_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
   {
       DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();        
       dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

       if (dataTable != null)
       {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

        GridViewStudents.DataSource = dataView;
        GridViewStudents.DataBind();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Sorting helper function

   ```
   private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
   {
       string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

       switch (sortDirection)
       {
           case SortDirection.Ascending:
               newSortDirection = "ASC";
               break;

           case SortDirection.Descending:
               newSortDirection = "DESC";
               break;
       }

       return newSortDirection;
   }
   ```